# Gltf 2.0 model not loading using ar.js

Tags: javascript, gltf, ar.js

I am trying  to load a `gltf2.0` model using `ar.js`. I have tried it several time but I think I am wrong at something. Here's the code:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/examples/vendor/aframe/build/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/master/dist/aframe-extras.loaders.min.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best;'>
      <a-anchor hit-testing-enabled='true'>
      <a-gltf-model-next src="damagedHelmet/damagedHelmet.gltf" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-gltf-model>
      </a-anchor>
        <a-camera-static/>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

The folder of gltf model is in the same folder in which the html code is.
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: With A-Frame >= 0.7.0, you should not need extras or `gltf-model-next`. Just use `gltf-model`. Also, could you check that the model works on this [drag-and-drop viewer](http://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/)? If not, there may be a problem with the model itself.

Comment: thanx for the answer the model is working fine on the viewer. And changing `gltf-model-next` to `gltf-model` is also not helping.Can you please share me any piece of html where a certain gltf model is loaded with updated version of libraries or can share the syntax for the same

Comment: I don't know whether AR.js requires a particular version of A-Frame, but working examples with just A-Frame 0.7.0 are [here](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/master/examples/animation/index.html#L24) or [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/primitives/a-gltf-model.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue with old `aframe` builds, however your code has extra issues. Bump up your `aframe` version and `aframe-ar` version. Remove the `aframe-extras` script, it's not necessary in the new builds. Get rid of the `a-anchor` and finally add a marker with `a-marker-camera`:

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.8.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.5/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best;'>
      <a-gltf-model src="https://rawgit.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/DamagedHelmet/glTF/DamagedHelmet.gltf"></a-gltf-model>
      <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
      <a-camera-static/>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

([run code](https://codepen.io/germanviscuso/pen/dePxXM)) ([download marker](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/data/data/Hiro%20pattern%20with%20border.pdf))

Alternatively, if you want to keep the old `aframe` library you can load the model using `a-assets` like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/examples/vendor/aframe/build/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/1.5.0/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>
<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
    <a-scene embedded arjs='trackingMethod: best;'>
    <a-assets>
    <a-asset-item id="model" src="https://rawgit.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/1.0/CesiumMan/glTF/CesiumMan.gltf" crossOrigin="anonymous"></a-asset-item> 
  </a-assets>
  <a-gltf-model src="#model"></a-gltf-model>
  <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
    <a-camera-static/>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

([run code](https://codepen.io/germanviscuso/pen/GdJKNY)) ([download marker](https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/blob/master/data/data/Hiro%20pattern%20with%20border.pdf))

but note that you'll only be able to load `gltf 1.0` models (the helmet is `gltf 2.0`)